# Why is this function so slow? How could I improve upon it?

Tags: python, export-to-csv

This function recieves a string and writes it into csv in utf-8 format:

```
def to_csv(string, name):
    with open("CSV_" + str(name[:-4]) + ".csv", 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as c:
        writer = csv.writer(c, delimiter=',')
        for i in range(len(string)):
            writer.writerow(string[i])
        c.write("\n")
    print("to_csv done")
```

But it's incredibly slow for some reason, I just can't figure out why.
The input string is a list of nouns, a list that started empty and I appended thousands of nouns in a function that takes way less.
These are the contents of the .csv it outputs as an example:

```
linktweet,urlajuntament,calvià,calvià,h
reyes,magos,repartiendo,ilusión,#calvià,#cabalgatadereyes,ajuntament,calvià,calvià
reyes,magos,repartirán,caramelos,#singlúten,gran,#cabalgata,calviànos,vemos,h,palmanova,ajuntament,calvià,calvià
buena,acogida,campaña,identificación,esterilización,gato,doméstico,calviàajuntament,calvià,calvià
extraído,toneladas,#residuossólidos,estaciones,bombeo,aguas,residuales,#calvià,ebar,tareas,limpieza,profundidad,instalaciones,ajuntament,calvià,calvià
fotos,gran,cabalgata,#ilusión,ajuntament,calvià,calvià
primera,presentación,avance,pgou,#calvià,ciudadanía,#participación,#transparencia,ajuntament,calvià,calvià
reunión,alianza,municipios,turísticos,sol,playa,fitur,seguimos,trabajando,mejorar,destino,#turismo,ajuntament,calvià,calvià
entrega,premios,ith,smart,destination,awards,#fitur,ajuntament,calvià,calvià
teniente,alcalde,turismo,reúne,director,oficina,española,turismo,frankfurt,#fiturajuntament,calvià,calvià
seguimos,#fitur,trabajando,promocionar,#calvià,destino,lleno,oportunidades,año,ajuntament,calvià,calvià
entrevista,hablar,#turismoajuntament,calvià,calvià
saludado,alumnado,turismo,ies,calvià,#fiturajuntament,calvià,calvià
agenda,encontrarás,actividades,realizan,municipio,pierdas,ajuntament,calvià,calvià
```

Comment: `c.write("\n")` is not necessary.

Comment: @Haoliang I do it becouse I want the results in two columns

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `writerows` instead of `writerow` it will write all your strings altogether:

```
def to_csv(strings, name):
    with open("CSV_" + str(name[:-4]) + ".csv", 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as c:
        writer = csv.writer(c, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerows(strings)
    print("to_csv done")
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I did two tests with this but they actually took longer than usual :/ I just don't get how this function takes so long